# Can I throw an error in c code just like Rcpp's stop() in Julia

Tags: c++, c, julia

In my origin C++ code, I use `assert()`, but if I want to use this code in Julia, maybe I need to replace it with other functions. In R, I can use `Rcpp::stop()`. Is there any easy way to do it in Julia with C or C++ code.

And it seems that Julia does not have `R CMD check` like stuff yet. It does not check this kind of issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question here is what you want to achieve.

If `assert()` fits your purpose in C, you can use that in code called from Julia as well. Note that your julia session will be aborted if an error occurs, but if it is to indicate a programming error in your C code, that is probably totally fine.

If you want your Julia code to be able to programmatically handle the error condition (and get an exception in Julia), you need to use standard C-api practices, and return an error code from the entry point. After the `ccall`, you can check the error code and throw an exception in Julia. `jl_error()` is not recommended to use unless you write some very Julia specific C code.

Comment: R Core will force you to check this by R CMD check this:- Compiled code should never terminate the R process within which it is running. Thus C/C++ calls to assert/abort/exit, Fortran calls to STOP and so on must be avoided. Nor may R code call q(). And it seems that Rcpp package make sure it can always safely return a SEXP with Rcpp::stop() from C to R.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, you can `throw` some [exception](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/exceptions/), e.g. `std::runtime_error` like

```
throw std::runtime_error("bad error");
```

Read a lot more about how C++ handle exceptions (with all the intermediate nested  destructors automagically invoked).

In C code, you might use `longjmp` to come back to some point in your main loop (or main program), at some use of [setjmp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setjmp.3.html). Use it with great caution and read several things about it. The usual practice in C is to use error codes (like most C library functions do) and propagate them manually (or simply, `abort` or `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)` with some fatal message, maybe using `perror`)

Read also about [embedding Julia](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/embedding/), [Calling C & Fortran code from Julia](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/calling-c-and-fortran-code/#man-calling-c-and-fortran-code) and notice its `jl_error` thing.